# other ways to install android apps than google market?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, sony-xperia, x10

i have an old backup **Android** phone  (i can't say it's name cause it's marked as bad grammar for some stupid reason) that only has **android platform 2.1 (Eclair)** and only got market than play (google), but i can't log in to the market since it always says that my password is wrong. So i have find **other ways to install** them.

So how can i install the apps without market?

I have already tried to factory reset the phone, but it still says that the google mail password is wrong. so i have to find other ways to install the apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had done this earlier on my phone. Not sure if will work on Android 2.1. The easiest way I found was download the apk file. Store it on your SD card. Check the box that says unknown sources in your Application settings. This will allow you to install non Market Applications . Go to your SD card and click on the apk file in your SD card. Make sure the apk you download is compatible with your device.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can install applications from the Amazon App Store. You might also search the application you want online, and tons of sites will come up. You just download the apk file from there and add to your SD card. Then install the application. Ensure that it is compatible with your device.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the apk's directly from other websites. 
One is [AppLounge](http://www.applounge.in)